# Angular FormGroup set value from API database

Tags: angular

hello everyone i got problem when show value in angular forms from database API,
i have data from identity login employeeNumber and after that data from identity was automatic create to my api Employee, after that i want get that api to my forms booking, there is form employeeNumber,name, and function.

this is my image was i get value
[image]
this is my code component.ts

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {

    //from uis
    this.getDataFromUIS = this.employeeService.get();
    // this.bookingvehicleForm.patchValue(this.employeeMemberService.getUserLogin(this.getDataFromUIS.employeeNumber));
    this.tampung3 = this.employeeMemberService.getUserLogin(this.getDataFromUIS.employeeNumber)
    .subscribe(s => {
      this.employeModelTransaction = s;
    });
    console.log(this.getDataFromUIS);
    console.log(this.tampung3);
    this.buildForm();
  }

  // Set variable form
  private buildForm(): void {
    let bookingDate: any;
    if (this.bookingvehicle.bookingDate != null) {
      bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.bookingDate));
    }
    else {
      bookingDate = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date());
    }
    let startPeriodeBooking: any = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.startPeriodeBooking));
    let endPeriodeBooking: any = this.dateconverter.DateToDTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.endPeriodeBooking));
    let startHoursOfDeparture: any = this.dateconverter.TimeToTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.startHoursOfDeparture));
    let endHoursOfDeparture: any = this.dateconverter.TimeToTP(new Date(this.bookingvehicle.endHoursOfDeparture));

    this.bookingvehicleForm = this.fb.group({
      'id': [this.bookingvehicle.id],
      'employee': [this.tampung3.employeeNumber, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(55)])],
      'name': [this.tampung3.name, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'function' : [this.tampung3.function],
      //'function': [this.bookingvehicleForm.controls['function'].value.employee.function],
      'bookingDate': [bookingDate, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'startPeriodeBooking': [startPeriodeBooking, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'endPeriodeBooking': [endPeriodeBooking, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'destination': [this.bookingvehicle.destination, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'passenger': [this.bookingvehicle.passenger],
      'reason': [this.bookingvehicle.reason, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
      'driveMode': [this.bookingvehicle.driveMode, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)])],
      'startHoursOfDeparture': [startHoursOfDeparture],
      'endHoursOfDeparture': [endHoursOfDeparture],
    });
    console.log(this.bookingvehicleForm);
  };
```

why when i get from service the value was subcription? my problem is i cannot get value from service and show the value to my form

please help:)

```
public getUserLogin(employeeNumber: string){ 
   console.log(this.employeeMemberURL + 
   this.config.ApiEndPoint.master.Employee + "getUserLogin"+ "/" + employeeNumber);
   return this.http.get(this.employeeMemberURL + this.config.ApiEndPoint.master.Employee + "getUserLogin"+ "/" + employeeNumber)
                   .map(res => Helper.bufferToJSON(res)); 
}
```

Comment: where is your service call?

Comment: 'public getUserLogin(employeeNumber: string){
        console.log(this.employeeMemberURL
            + this.config.ApiEndPoint.master.Employee
            + "getUserLogin"+ "/" + employeeNumber);
        return this.http.get(this.employeeMemberURL
            + this.config.ApiEndPoint.master.Employee
            + "getUserLogin"+ "/" + employeeNumber)
            .map(res => Helper.bufferToJSON(res));
    }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting data and you are assigning the returning of `subscribe()` method to `this.tampung3` with this instruction

```
this.tampung3 = this.employeeMemberService.getUserLogin(this.getDataFromUIS.employeeNumber)
    .subscribe(s => {
      this.employeModelTransaction = s;
    });
```

But I think you want only data, so you should not manage `subscribe()` return type. You are assigning remote fetched data to `this.employeModelTransaction` with this statement:

```
this.employeModelTransaction = s;
```

And then you are never reading it.
So I think you should do something like this:

```
this.employeeMemberService.getUserLogin(this.getDataFromUIS.employeeNumber)
        .subscribe(s => {
          this.tampung3 = s;
        });
```

Comment: the variable you are assigning your data to: this.tampung3

Comment: like this? `'employee': [this.tampung3.employeeNumber, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(55)])],` or i must make new variable to assign tampung3?

Comment: the first time you should do is try it, because by this way, by making errors and analyzing them you will learn more things. however I think you should modify only the code I have posted. only `getUserLogin`'s subscribe body. if you have still problems let me know

Comment: you can see the problem in your answers :)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i mean i already run your answer and you can see the output in your answer, i will edit your answer with output

Comment: forgive me, the edit has been rejected. can you explain me what problem do you have? or please edit your question